# Prove that $\sup_{n\geq 1} |\alpha_n|<\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $\alpha=\{\alpha_n\}_{n\geq 1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_n x_n <\infty$, for every $x=\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}\in\ell_1$. The goal is to prove that $\sup_{n\geq 1} |\alpha_n|<\infty$.

I noticed that this is equivalent to proving that $\lVert \alpha\rVert_{\infty}<\infty$. However, I don't know how to start the proof. What I also noticed is that $\lVert \cdot\rVert_{\infty}$ is the natural norm of $c_0=\{x=\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}\subseteq\mathbb{R}: x_n\rightarrow 0\}$ and $c_0^* = \ell_1$, where $c_0^*$ denotes the dual space of $c_0$, but I don't know if this is useful for the proof.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you're supposed to be approaching this a little more naively. While $\ell^1$ is indeed basically $c_0^*$, this is a step in proving that $(\ell^1)^*$ is basically $\ell^\infty$. Anyway, as a hint, prove the contrapositive. If $\sup_n |a_n| = \infty$ then $|a_{n_k}| \ge k$ for some subsequence $k$. Can you think of a sequence $x_n$ that makes the sum of $\alpha_nx_n$ infinite?

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\sup |\alpha_n|=\infty$. Then there is a sequence $a_{n_k}$ with $|a_{n_k}|>k$. Choose now $x_n\in l_1$ with $x_{n_k}=\operatorname{sign}(\alpha_{n_k})/k^2$ and the rest of its elements equal zero.
Then
$$
\sum \alpha_n x_n>\sum_k \frac 1{k}=\infty,
$$
contradicting your assumption.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: @GReyes I would choose $\alpha_{n_k}>k^2,$ or even $\alpha_{n_k}>2^k$ and $x_{n_k}=2^{-k}.$

Comment: Technically all you can get is a sequence with $|\alpha_{n_k}| > k$ - but of course your argument can be saved by choosing the sign of $x_{n_k}$ so that $\alpha_{n_k} x_{n_k} > 0$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen You are right, thanks! I edited my answer.